# Localization in asp.net 4.0 with FireFox

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, localization

I need to localize my project in finnish language. I have used asp.net 4.0 (c#) for my work. I followed all necessary steps to do this. For example, I want to localize my Default.aspx page. For this purpose, I have created a resource file named "Default.aspx.fi-FI.resx" in Local Resource folder. I have set all necessary Key/Value pair in this resource file and also set necessary changes in browser. My purpose perfectly servers in Internet Explorer. But it doesn't work in Firefox. It is badly needed to work it with firefox. Can anybody help me to do this?

Thanks in advance.

BR,
Golam Rabbi

Answer (score 0):

The language displayed will be determined by the language Firefox sets as it's preferred language in the request header.

To change this, in Firefox, go to Tools -> Options -> Content Tab -> Languages -> Choose and set Finnish as the preferred language.

Comment: Rich, I have already done this very first. But it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @GolamRabbi Are you able to install Fiddler to see what the `Accept-Language` header is when you use IE and again using Firefox?